# CCNode : help interpreting objective C , in a compound iVar assignement

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In CCNode (cocos version 1.0.1), i see the following line in various setters.

```
isTransformDirty_ = isInverseDirty_ = YES;
```

My IDE whines about the fact that we are "Using a '=' in a conditional". I read this as setting both iVars to YES. Am I correct in my interpretation (and thus my faithful IDE behaving as a drama queen) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is correct, this is an assignment of `YES` to both variables. You may try silencing it with parentheses (which may or may not work)

```
isTransformDirty_ = (isInverseDirty_ = YES);
```

or to add a `#pragma` to ignore the issue (this is highly compiler/IDE dependent).

Comment: thanks, i'll post a bug report onto the appropriate 'authorities'

Comment: @YvesLeBorg It may not be a bug, but a feature. When you build a code checked that scans for potential coding problems (as opposed to definite coding problems, such as syntax errors) you weigh the probability of uncovering a bug against a probability of a false positive. In this case it looks like the probability of false positive was low enough for the IDE manufacturers to issue a warning.

Comment: Surely your are not suggesting that i 'nicht gefingerpoken' !!! I'll keep your caution in mind, good point about the statistical nature of any alarm. Although, that IDE mfg is usually quite good about 'false positives' in other languages/environments. Thanks.

Comment: news update : that specific 'false positive' is already one of the enhancement requests scheduled in the next minor release (currently under community testing).

Comment: We all know that this IDE can only be AppCode so you could as well just mention that. :)
Personally I think the compiler is right to complain if the left hand is a BOOL value, since you could have meant to write isTransformDirty_ = (isInverseDirty_ == YES); although it's kind of odd. But so is writing the original line in the first place, just to save one additional line by introducing obscurity and ambiguity. Never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:
`isTransformDirty_ = YES;`
and `isInverseDirty_ = YES;`?

Comment: I would not know, I did not write that snippet, and am not certain whether this form 'embeds' some kind of optimization.

Comment: @Jeeter Its a certain style of coding that in addition to setting both  iVars to YES also conveys that they are to be set to the same value.  Splitting it across two lines removes that additional bit of information and would require two code changes in the future if they needed to be set to NO.  However in this case this programming style doesn't really seem necessary as the iVars don't seem to be related.    If the iVars were related (say the heights of two boxes that needed to initially match) then this style makes more sense.

Comment: @PeterM : yes for the maintainability aspect.

Comment: @PeterM Thank you for that, it does seem more reliable if you want to set a whole list of values to the same one.

Comment: Agree with Peter and like to add that it's hardly ever necessary to change both values. If that's the case it seems like both variables would be closely linked, and one could ask if they serve the same purpose and should be merged into a single variable, or an enumeration.